# Can SQL Server 2019 SSMS client connect to database server with SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I faced an error login failed for "user" when I tried to connect remote database test server with SQL Server 2000 compatibility using client tool (SSMS Tool 18.x /SQL Server 2019 database engine).

```
Server Name: --db server ip--
Error Number: 18456
Severity: 14
State: 1
Line Number: 65536
```

But when I tried to connect an other remote test database server with SQL Server 2008 compatibility, there's no such issue & successfully connected.

I'm quite confused that does SSMS tool itself have such limitation when connecting different database compatibility? Is SQL Server backward compatibility usually refer to SSMS tool or database itself?

Comment: Refer to `SSMS 18` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15 `This version of SSMS works with all supported versions of SQL Server 2008 - SQL Server 2019 (15.x)`

Comment: First of all the error returned for 18456 is deliberately obfuscated, so you don't get the true error (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15#additional-error-information)  Go to the SQL Server error log and grab the error from there and post that as it will provide more insight.   Secondly - is it a SQL 2000 instance or a database with DB Compatibility set to 80?   I'm not sure what you are referring to with "SQL Server 2000 Compatibility"

Comment: The [database compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level) does not affect the wire protocol used between SQL Server and clients. Are you sure you're not actually trying to connect to an SQL Server 2000 instance? If so you'll need to find old client tools that can talk TDS 7.1 (Tabular Data Stream)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning. That's my point. How to determine which TDS version that client side or server side using? any commands or third party software to do that ?

Comment: TDS protocol versions are tied to SQL Server versions. TDS is documented at [MS-TDS: Tabular Data Stream Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/b46a581a-39de-4745-b076-ec4dbb7d13ec) and a matrix of TDS protocol versions vs. SQL Server versions is at [Appendix A: Product Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/135d0ebe-5c4c-4a94-99bf-1811eccb9f4a). If you find a version of SSMS that says it can connect to SQL Server 2000 that basically means that it supports TDS 7.1.

Comment: Your best bet may be going through your collection of MSDN CDs and DVDs for an SQL Server 2000 disc and doing a Client Tools installation from sqlsetup.exe